# Unity (2022.3.3f1) Issues with serialization and generics

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I was trying to do a Translation System with properties, those properties i need that they can be of any type then i used generics, but for some reason unity can't serialize them, here the files:

Base Class

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

[Serializable]
public abstract class TranslationProperty : ScriptableObject
{
    [field: SerializeField]
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    public abstract void SetValue(object newValue);
    public abstract object GetValue();
    public static T CreateInstance<T>(string name, string value) where T : TranslationProperty
    {
        var instance = CreateInstance<T>();
        instance.Name = name;
        instance.init(value);
        return instance;
    }
    protected abstract void init(string value);
    public abstract TranslationProperty Clone();
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    public bool Foldout = false;
    public abstract void OnInspector();
#endif
}
```

Generic Class

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif
[Serializable]
public abstract class TranslationProperty<T> : TranslationProperty
{
    [field: SerializeField]
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public override object GetValue()
        => Value;
    public override void SetValue(object newValue)
        => Value = (T)newValue;
    public abstract T Parse(string value);
    public override TranslationProperty Clone()
    {
        TranslationProperty<T> instance = (TranslationProperty<T>)getInstance();
        instance.Name = Name;
        instance.SetValue(Value);
        return instance;
    }
    protected abstract TranslationProperty getInstance();
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
    protected override void init(string value)
    {
        Value = Parse(value);
    }
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    public override void OnInspector()
    {
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField($"Property {Name}");
    }
#endif
}
```

SubClass:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif
[Serializable]
public class IntProp : TranslationProperty<int>
{
    public override int Parse(string value)
        => int.Parse(value);
    protected override TranslationProperty getInstance()
        => CreateInstance<IntProp>();
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    public override void OnInspector()
    {
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        base.OnInspector();
        Value = EditorGUILayout.IntField(Value);
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }
#endif
}
```

I really don't know what is failing because all properties/fields have the SerializeField, the base class inherit from ScriptableObject and all use [Serializable].
For this i did a test class:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TestTranslation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public IntProp prop;
}
```

Also an editor for that test:

```
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(TestTranslation))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class TestTranslationEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        TestTranslation t = (TestTranslation)target;

        if (t.prop == null)
            t.prop = TranslationProp.CreateInstance<IntProp>("prop1", "0");
        t.prop.OnInspector();

        EditorUtility.SetDirty(t);
    }
}
```

I would like that the property is serialized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Various questions/Issues:

- First you create instances of your `ScriptableObject` but you never actually save them as asset! They only exist as runtime instances and will be gone on domain reload

  If this is actually intended to be `ScriptableObject` **asset** you also would want to store those using e.g. [`AssetDatabase.CreateAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.CreateAsset.html)
- If those are `ScriptableObject` then the `[Serializable]` does actually nothing. If you rather wanted these to be serialized as a normal value based class rather then asset references then **do not make it a `ScriptableObject`**
- [Minor] If those are `ScriptableObject` it already has the built-in `name` property anyway and you wouldn't need your own
- [Secondary] If you already have a generic method for creating instances I would rather extend the type parameter and do e.g.

  ```
   public static TProperty CreateInstance<TProperty, TValue>(string name, TValue value) where TProperty : TranslationProperty<TValue>
   {
        var instance = CreateInstance<T>();
        instance.name = name;
        instance.Value = Value;
        return instance;
   }
  ```
- [Secondary] Instead of your `OnInspector` method would usually rather implement a proper CustomEditor for your `ScriptableObject`. Then if you really want to integrate it into your component as well you could additionally implement a [CustomPropertyDrawer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html) and reuse the custom editor code for displaying it.
- If those are `ScriptableObject` unity also provides a built-in way for creating clones: `Instantiate`
- Finally you should not go through the `target` in most cases but rather through the `serializedObject` and `SerializedProperty`s. Your `SetDirty` even though there are no changes is quite a hack and probably causes more issues than it solves - for instance your current scene will also be marked as not saved which is at best confusing for the user.

So main thing to solve as a first step: Should this be a `ScriptableObject` at all?

- Yes: You will have to properly create the actual assets for them
- No - meaning it should be simply `[Serializable]` classes: Rather go for a [CustomPropertyDrawer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html) instead and let the built-in Inspector system handle the dirty marking etc

Answer (score 0):

- It is not necessary save those instances as assets. In others clases or objectes, i had scriptable objects and they were saved correctly without saving them in a asset, in this case didnt work because the generic for some reason.
- I know that but i put the [Serializable] because i wasnt able to make it serializable.
- Yeah but i prefer a separate name for the property and other for the scriptable object.
- No because the value is obtained from a json file then is better use string in this case.
- I know that but create a method "OnInspector" in the class allows more flexibility and also is easier to use in some cases. For example in this case i use inheritance and use prop.OnInspector() allows to have one implementation for each sub class.
- Yeah but that don't setup the variables in the way that i want.
- This is a good advise, i will consider it.

Probably i can remove the inheritance from scriptableobject , i used it because usually scriptable offers some things that can be useful in some context but maybe in this case it is not necessary.

I was able to serialize the class removing the generic, but that provokes that i need to repeat some code, not the best way to do it, I don't know why the generic breaks the serialization.

Answer (score 0):

I tried without using scriptable object but unity only can serialize subclasses when they inherit from scriptable object or monobehaviour. I didnt need to save the scriptable object on an asset, worked without that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).